# How do I properly open a SSH tunnel in the background?

Tags: ssh

I wish to tunnel a port over SSH from a remote host. I wish to implement this as an [`oclif`](https://oclif.io/) plugin; I want the user experience to look like this:

```
laptop$ give-jupyter
http://localhost:4040/
laptop$ kill-jupyter
laptop$
```

...and that should be relatively straightforward; I just* need to maintain a pidfile, right? Something like:

```js
import child_process from 'child_process';
const childProcess = child_process.spawn('ssh', [/* flags */], {detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'});
childProcess.unref();
writeToSomePidfile({childProcess.pid);
```

However, all of this is basically besides the point. The problem is I have to figure those flags out! Well, okay; this works:

```sh
laptop$ ssh machine -L 4040:localhost:4040
machine$
```

...however, it also opens a shell on the remote end. No problem, `man ssh` says that's what `-L` is for:

```sh
laptop$ ssh machine -LN 4040:localhost:4040
```

That's great, but it's now taking my user's shell hostage. Fine, let's just send the process to the background:

```sh
laptop$ ssh machine -LN 4040:localhost:4040 &
laptop$ f
f: file not found
laptop$ fg
^C
```

The background version of `ssh` enters a race condition with the shell over `STDIN`, and everything is positively terrible. Fine, `man ssh` says that's what `-n` is for:

```sh
laptop$ ssh machine -nLN 4040:localhost:4040 &
laptop$Job 1, 'ssh machine -nNL 40…' has ended
```

...well, that's just great: `ssh` now quits immediately, and so does the tunnel.

SSH mentions `-f` should enable some sort of background mode, but `ssh -fnN` doesn't do it either; `ssh` quits immediately still.

If I can't have nice things, maybe I can approximate them with a command that will run forever even with no STDIN. Server Fault [suggests](https://serverfault.com/questions/358866/create-unix-named-socket-from-the-command-line):

```sh
laptop$ ssh machine -nL 4040:localhost:4040 tail -f /dev/null &
laptop$
```

Still no good?! Fine:

```sh
laptop$ ssh machine -nL 4040:localhost:4040 sleep infinity &
laptop$
```

That seems to work at the low, low cost of one tiny process, a far sight better than other iterations I had tried while writing this questions, mostly involving `yes`...

Is there however a... less kludgy way to run an SSH tunnel in the background? Bonus points: I need this to work on OSX laptops too...

Comment: ...one weird thing about this is that I can run multiple copies of this and it'll work, which is not what I expected; I rather expected ssh to complain that the ports were already in use

Comment: Sounds like the tunnels weren't properly created at all times. use `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 4040` to see if there are port binding?

Answer (score 10):

I'd personally create a file on the system that binds to the tunnel using `-S` control socket. Easier than dealing with PIDs for sure.

### Open tunnel

```sh
ssh -M -S ~/jupyter-tunnel -o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes" -fN machine -L 4040:localhost:4040
```

### Close tunnel

```sh
ssh -S ~/jupyter-tunnel -O exit machine
```

Comment: for everybody wondering: [`-m    Places the ssh client into “master” mode for connection sharing.  Multiple -M options places ssh into “master” mode but with confirmation required using ssh-askpass(1) before each operation that changes the multiplexing state (e.g. opening a new session).  Refer to the description of ControlMaster in ssh_config(5) for details.`](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ssh1.html)